# Pseudocode with calling function for multiple test scores letter grade?

Tags: pseudocode

how do I call this function for multiple test scores in pseudocode? So far I have:

```
    Function String determineGrade(Real number)
     if score >= 90
      return "A"
     else if score >= 80
      return "B"
     else if score >= 70
      return "C"
     else if score >= 60
      return "D"
     else
      return "F"
     end if
    End function
```

How will I call this function so it will display 10 different test letter grade with 10 different inputs i recieved from user in pseudocode? Thanks

Comment: The function has just one argument (`number`). You can call it repeatedly, providing a different input each time.

Comment: How do I call it repeatedly?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are getting grades from array or randomly creating them.  For array for example you can do this.

```
Function String name() // type can be void if you are printing
     for i=0, i<10, i++
       determineGrade(number[i])
```

Comment: Its not from array or random. Its just from me prompting the user 5 times for them to enter test scores 5 different times.

Comment: then you can do
count = 5
while (count > 0){
   scan num 
  determineGrade(num)
 count--
}